# Text different position from Illustrator to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I have created a design using Adobe Illustrator and when copy and pasting this design in Adobe Photoshop(as Smart Object or Pixel) the text is not keeping its original position. Any idea on how I can fix this, please? Images attached.

Adobe Illustrator:
[image]

Adobe Photoshop:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the font is not available to PS

Comment: These aren't the same font, so there's some font substitution going on, nothing to do with the position. No idea why. I can't replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the font is not updated when you paste it on Photoshop artboard.

Select the text in Illustrator, go to Object > Expand, select both. Then copy it and paste in Photoshop.

Comment: Yep, thanks. That did the trick!